# OrientDB: add metadata to a class

Tags: orientdb

I need to add metadata to a vertex class.
I want to store the canonical name of the java class in the Vertex class definition as a metadata so later I could ask for it to instantiate and hydrate an object.
Are there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define CUSTOM metadata by using [ALTER CLASS command](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Alter-Class.html). Example.

```
ALTER CLASS Post CUSTOM javaClass="com.my.Post"
```

So you can retrieve that custom property through API or SQL.

For more information look at the official documentation about it: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Alter-Class.html.

Comment: Excelent Luca! I'am workin in an Objecto to Graph Mapper to work with OrientDB. It is working fine. Now I'am improvement the query access.

Comment: Unfortunatly no. I need to port an app developed in DB4O so what I'am doing is to bring a clear Object to DB access like DB4O had. 
Currently is still in development but all day working on. You can see it at https://github.com/mdre/odbogm/